# Lasso and SGDRegressor are not working well

Tags: regression, lasso, ridge-regression

I want to fit some data using `Lasso`, `Ridge` and `SGDRegressor` and to compare the results.

Before trying to fit data from the lab where I work, I tried to create some examples and see how they worked.

In this way, I tried to fit some functions, but the results that I get when using Lasso and SGDRegressor are horrible. The function I am trying to fit is $F(t)=2t^2+3 \exp(t)$.

Here is my code:

```py
##Generating data

t = np.linspace(1, 100, 1000)

Y = np.array(2*t*t+3*np.exp(t)) #target data

a = np.array(t)
b = np.array(t*t)
c = np.array(t*t*t*t)
d = np.array(np.exp(t))

y = y.reshape(100,1)
X = np.stack((a, b, c, d), axis=-1)


##Creating the model

model=Lasso()
model.fit(X, Y)
model.coef_
```

Instead of getting the coefs:(0,2,0,0,3), what I get is coefs=array([-9.73598193e+37,  1.67208218e+36,  3.00006032e+00, -8.99310647e+31]), which definitely is totally wrong. This always happens even tuning the alpha parameter.

Something similar takes place when trying to use `SGDRegressor`, on the contrary I get more or less fair results when using `Ridge`. Interestingly, when I use `SDGRegressor(penalty='l2')` it still working awful. This confused me because I though that using `Ridge` or `SDGRegressor(penalty='l2')` where equivalent.

Please, can someone give some insight in what is going on?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to fit a linear model to some very non-linear data with huge values (`Y` ranges from about 10 to 8.06e+43!). Gradient Descent does not like features with very different scales. Lasso and Ridge either. I strongly suggest you try your experiments with simpler features first. Try some linear data with a bit of noise. And if you really want to keep your current model, then at least try it on a range of `t` where `Y` will not be so huge. And try using a `StandardScaler` to scale the data.

**Edit**

Also, `Ridge` is equivalent to `SGDRegressor(loss="squared_error", penalty="l2", alpha=alpha / len(X), max_iter=100_000, tol=None, eta0=0.0001, learning_rate="constant")`.

Notice that we use `alpha / len(X)`, not `alpha`. That's because `Ridge` minimizes the Sum of Squared Errors + alpha * l2_penalty, while `SGDRegressor` minimizes the Mean Squared Error + alpha * l2_penalty. Since the MSE is equal to the SSE divided by `len(X)`, we also need to divide `alpha` by `len(X)`.

Also, `SGDRegressor` uses a learning rate schedule by default, and it stops when there's little change for several epochs, which means that it tends to stop a little bit early, before convergence is absolutely complete. That's usually ok in practice, but if you want to see very similar results, you need to set `learning_rate="constant"` and set `eta0` to a small value (to make little steps and get more precise convergence), but it will take more iterations so you need `max_iter` to be a large value, and set `tol=None` to force it to continue for `max_iter` epochs.

FYI, `Lasso` minimizes the MSE + alpha * l1_penalty, so there's no need to divide `alpha` by `len(X)` when using an `SGDRegressor`, it's equivalent to `SGDRegressor(loss="squared_error", penalty="l1", alpha=alpha, max_iter=100_000, tol=None, eta0=0.0001, learning_rate="constant")`